# How to expose application on port 5000 on Elastic Beanstalk with prod profile (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my application to Elastic Beanstalk, I want the application to be exposed on port 5000.

Here is my application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod

server:
  port: 5000
```

And I have added the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE env variable in the Environment Variables in EB

[image]

However, the Health is still in Severe status so I guess the app is still being exposed on 8080. Any ideas where I am going. wrong? Cheers

Comment: This configuration looks correct so don't just assume that it's still listening on port 8080. Using EB, download your application logs and look for the line Tomcat started on port(s):, you'll likely find that your application is running on port 5000 and there are other reasons your healthcheck is failing, or you just haven't given it enough time to become healthy. – lane.maxwell 11 mins ago   Delete

Comment: @lane.maxwell thanks, after looking at the logs I discovered my app was crashing for another reason.